# MongoDB how to change field type in array from string to array and keep original value

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongo-shell

Image of original
[document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZu1C.png)

I have db "test" with collection "testing". In that collection I have document with array called "methods" which contains object 0(and maybe lot more objects 1,2,3,4...). Inside those objects I have string field "tool" with tool "xray". I want that string field "tool" to be array of tools. I found command to change tool field to array with:

```
db.testing.update(
  {},
  [{ $set: { "methods.tool": ["$methods.tool"] } }],
  { multi: true }
)
```

This works but it creates one extra array "0:Array" and I dont want that

[Outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MyFji.png)

I want the end result look like this:
[end result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8n9uc.png)

Comment: Note that will not work the way you expect if the "methods" array has more than one element.

Comment: if you can next time give data in text JSON, it would be much easier, don't send images for things that text can be used, so people can test on your data and give you a query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query

- `$map` to update all document members of methods
- `$$this` is the current member each time
- `$mergeObjects` is used to add the updated field, were `tool:xray` becomes `tool : [xray]`

*paths that the field is part of array, they are arrays also, "$methods.tool" is an array of all the tools in all methods.

[Test code here](https://cmql.org/play/?q=70176492)

```js
update(
{},
[{"$set": 
    {"methods": 
      {"$map": 
        {"input": "$methods",
          "in": {"$mergeObjects": ["$$this", {"tool": ["$$this.tool"]}]}}}}}],
{"multi": true})
```